# Response of JSONSerialization.jsonObject is nil with the method POST in swift 3

Tags: json, swift3, null, response, ios10

this is an example for something i want to do but  the line `if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: String]` is `false` because the return of `JSONSerialization.jsonObject` is `nil`

```
func parser(lbl: UILabel){
    let postString = "xxx=xxx&xxxx=xxxx==&xxxxx=xxxxx&xxxxxx=xxxxxx&xx=xx"

    let url = URL(string: "http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx.php")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else {
            lbl.text = "error";

            return
        }

        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: String] {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    let error = Int(json["success"]!)

                    let message = json["message"]
                    lbl.text = message
                }
            } 
        } catch let parseError {
            print("error to parse: \(parseError)")

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("response`enter code here` : \(responseString!)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your `JSON` response no one can tell you what is wrong with your parsing method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
var resultFromServer: Any?
resultFromServer = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
```

This should give you resultFromServer as type of `Any?`, simply check and typecast depending on the basis of the response you are getting, an array or a dictionary.

**Like**

```
if let respdict = resultFromServer as? [String : Any] {
//respone in dictionary format
}

else if let respArr = resultFromServer as? [Any]{
//response is array type
}

else if let stringRespt = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8){
//resp is string                                
}
```

Just make changes as per your JSON

Comment: Don't use `.mutableContainers`, since it has no effect in `Swift`. The mutability of the whole `JSON` object depends on whether you declare it using the `let` or `var` keyword.

Comment: Thanks! Your code helped me alot,  but now I have another mistake!
The method POST is sending the params like "" i mean empty to the web service

Comment: Can you provide me a suggestion to replace .mutableContainers?

Comment: Ok so there is no response right ? You are getting empty string?

Comment: i've added it to the answer make logics to check if response is string, array or dictionary..

Comment: @UmarFarooque I add the three conditions and is entering in the dictionary condition and the string response, the response is the next one (an example) in the two conditions:
{"success":0,"message":""}

Comment: @AxelLópez you have to use it with If-else condition, and also can you show your JSON response, it will make it clearer

Comment: {"success":0,"message":""}

the success is 0 and the message is empty, but in my web service i always put a error message or a successful message

Comment: @AxelLópez I think for that you will need to check out yourself why message is empty. In code you can try to put a breakpoint and check the value of dictionary. But I guess the scope of the question is covered and answered. Check the for reference and accept the answer.  https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

Comment: Thanks for everything @UmarFarooque